# Rotate dataset in specific order using python

Tags: python, dataframe, sorting, rotation

Using Iris dataset as an example I am interested in sorting by species order (so that it comes as 1,2,3,1,2,3...)  then by descending order of petal length as illustrated in expected output.

% dist column, is calculated by the sum of petal length for each species divided by total petal length across whole dataframe.

As you can see that species order is higher priority than order of petal length and you may have more number in particular species name.

**Expected output:**

| petal length (cm) | petal width (cm) | sepal length (cm) | sepal width (cm) | Species | % dist | Species order |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 6.2 | 3.5 | 5.3 | 6.5 | virginica | 0.19 | 1 |
| 5.6 | 2.0 | 6.6 | 3.0 | setosa | 0.39 | 2 |
| 9.1 | 7.9 | 7.7 | 5.2 | versicolor | 0.42 | 3 |
| 4.0 | 5.5 | 0.2 | 7.8 | virginica | 0.19 | 1 |
| 5.0 | 8.8 | 1.4 | 2.5 | setosa | 0.39 | 2 |
| 7.0 | 9.8 | 8.3 | 3.1 | versicolor | 0.42 | 3 |
| 4.3 | 1.3 | 5.9 | 2.8 | setosa | 0.39 | 2 |
| 3.2 | 7.6 | 5.6 | 7.9 | versicolor | 0.42 | 3 |
| 4.2 | 0.7 | 4.4 | 6.9 | setosa | 0.39 | 2 |
| 2.3 | 5.0 | 2.1 | 7.2 | versicolor | 0.42 | 3 |
| 1.5 | 0.2 | 5.0 | 3.4 | setosa | 0.39 | 2 |
| 0.5 | 0.4 | 7.3 | 9.0 | versicolor | 0.42 | 3 |

I have tried using sort_values() in python but it doesn't quite work out, as all species are sorted by species order and not in a rotate format as I would like. My actual dataframe has over a million rows so manually rotating it is not a feasible solution. Any suggestions on how this can be done in python would be great. Thank you!

Comment: Are you intending to rank the species? See: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rank.html

Comment: How do you decide, for example, which of the many rows with species=1 goes first? Second?  Third? ...

Comment: @ScottHunter
The decision of which species goes first is determine by %dist column, which is the sum pf petal length for each species divided by sum of petal length in whole dataframe. It literally is the size of % distribution of petal length.  I just want to show for each species (from smallest size of % distribution), their max petal length in that iteration. Hope that make sense

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC correctly you're sorting by petal length descending and then you want to alternate each species in the data frame.

Loading the data frame from sklearn, this has a different order of species than your example, but the approach is similar

```
from sklearn import datasets
iris = datasets.load_iris()
df = pd.DataFrame(np.hstack((iris['data'], iris['target'].reshape(iris['target'].shape[0],1))),columns= iris['feature_names'] + ['order'])
```

Sort and then alternate rows:

```
final_df, order = [], []
# df = df.sample(frac=1) # shuffle the rows if needed

for name,group in df.groupby('order'):
  group = group.sort_values(['petal length (cm)'], ascending=False)
  group = group.reset_index().drop(columns='index')
  final_df.append(group)
  order.append(name)

# You can sort by whatever "order" you want
final_df = [final_df[int(i)] for i in order]

out = pd.concat(final_df).sort_index(kind='merge')
print(out[['petal length (cm)', 'order']].head(15))
```

Output:

```
   petal length (cm)  order
0                1.9    0.0
0                5.1    1.0
0                6.9    2.0
1                1.9    0.0
1                5.0    1.0
1                6.7    2.0
2                1.7    0.0
2                4.9    1.0
2                6.7    2.0
3                1.7    0.0
3                4.9    1.0
3                6.6    2.0
4                1.7    0.0
4                4.8    1.0
4                6.4    2.0
```

Comment: Thank you for your solution but your solution doesn't quite work out as you pointed out that I have slightly modified the Iris dataset so that it contains uneven number of species  name, so by creating the 'order' method as you suggested here seems to create this IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: `final_df = [x for _, x in sorted(zip(order, final_df))]` try this as your sort then, instead of `final_df = [final_df[int(i)] for i in order]`